# Ive got an Eth wallet for which I have damaged my private key I have 59-60 out of 64 characters in order and the public ID - need to brute force guess

Tags: python, passphrase

Ive got an Eth wallet for which I have damaged my private key I have 59-60 out of 64 characters in order and the public ID - need to brute force guess the password how do I do this quickly and effectively is there software I can use for my metamask wallet to get access. I do not have the seed phrase. Just 90% of the private key in order and the public ID. Assistance needed as I wish to get access to my now frozen funds.

Comment: This is for a Metamask wallet by the way for clarity.

Comment: I'm not aware of any particular tool for this, but it should be practically feasible to iterate over the (roughly) 1 million possibilities and compare it with the address to find the match.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely. You could do something like this on Python:

```
hexAddress = blocksmith.EthereumWallet.generate_address(format(privateKey))
```

Using a for loop and importing the blocksmith libary, you should have the result in less than 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ethers.js library and a bit of javascript code to brute-force it. For instance, lets say you're missing the last 4 digits. Since ethereum addresses use hexadecimal values (from 0 to f), it means each of those 4 digits has 16 different variations of what it could be. Since you have 4 of them, then 16^4 (65536) is all the possible variations that could exist of missing characters for that private key, so code similar to the following would work:

```
let ethers = require("ethers");//importing the ethers library

//hexadecimal values
let h = {
"0": "0",
"1": "1",
"2": "2",
"3": "3",
"4": "4",
"5": "5",
"6": "6",
"7": "7",
"8": "8",
"9": "9",
"10": "a",
"11": "b",
"12": "c",
"13": "d",
"14": "e",
"15": "f",
}

//private and public key information you have available
let privateKeyKnown = "0xab135ab135ab135ab135ab135ab135ab135ab135ab135ab135ab135ab135";
let publicAddress = "0xzxy33zxy33zxy33zxy33zxy33zxy33zxy33zxy33"

function bruteForce() {
    for (let i = 0; i< 16; i++) {
        for (let ii = 0; ii< 16; ii++) {
            for (let iii = 0; iii< 16; iii++) {
                for (let iiii = 0; iiii< 16; iiii++) {
                    let buffer = new ethers.Wallet(privateKeyKnown + h[i] + h[ii] + h[iii] + h[iiii]);
                    if (buffer.address === publicAddress) {
                        console.log("Found the private key!: " + privateKeyKnown + h[i] + h[ii] + h[iii] + h[iiii]);
                        return;
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log("...");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

bruteForce();
```

**Explanation:** The brute force will test out the different options, and when the public address that is made from that private key matches the public address that you provided, then the brute force finishes, and it then spits out the 4 missing characters you needed in the private key.

Let me know if that helped